# Google Assistant - Keep asking to turn on personal results even it's on

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I have registered a device model in Google Action console, I have enabled the 'personal results' setting in Google Home app-> device setting.
When I am trying to control my TV, it's asking to turn on personal results even though it's on in both the device settings.
I am using [Google Assistant SDK](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-testing-nodejs).